# String comparison ignoring realtime factors like date and time

Tags: regex, string

I want to compare two string ignoring real time factors like date and time which can be in any locale.
Consider following example.

    string str1= "ACV INDIA LIBRARY ABC.APPLE PATH="G\XXXX....\INDIA\ABC.EFG" <> 03/06/2011  9:24:00 AM"
    
string str2= "ACV INDIA LIBRARY ABC.APPLE PATH="G\XXXX....\INDIA\ABC.EFG" <> 03/07/2011  9:24:00 AM"

Note: Position of date and time is not fixed.

result of comparison should return as true

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: Remove the date and time and then compare.

Comment: I tried this approach. But it fails in some scenarios.

Comment: Also searching of date and time entities is also difficult

Comment: @Phil- Date can be represented in many ways dd/mm/yy, dd/mm/yyy, mm/dd/yy, mm/dd/yyyy, or 1st Sept, 20011. etc..... and time can also be represented in many ways 10:00, 10:00 AM/PM, 23:00. I was not able to figure out the kind of regular expression which I need to use. As we go on with more and more time format. It fails somewhere.

Comment: @Amit - You may not be able to do it as just 1 regular expression. You may need to use 3 or 4.

Comment: Both the given answer and all of the comments have offered you the best answer considering your scenario. It's going to be difficult to escape needing a RegEx (perhaps several) without standardizing your string format to guarantee the datetime at some position for easy removal.

Comment: Why is this tagged both C# and java but looks like neither? That code doesn't compile in C#.

Comment: @Michael- It not related to any programming language. It won't compile. It's just the plain text. It's a concept which is not technology dependent.

Comment: Oh, in that case: Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely your date/times follow some standard that you have knowledge of.  Use a regular expression to match the date/times, remove them, and do a standard string comparison on the resulting strings.

If you want your program to be powerful enough to recognize different formats of dates, then you'll have to do the work of setting it up to recognize them.  Run it through a different regexp for every kind of date/time format you can think of (and are willing to accept).  Date/time strings are completely matchable by regular expressions; they are the optimal solution.

Comment: After googling found out this [link](http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=4&categoryid=5&p=1) site. This site contains most of the regular expression that can be thought of for date and time. Implementation will be time consuming but can guarantee the result